# Malfunctioning Raspberry pi 4, red and green led on all the time

Tags: boot, led, pi-4, firmware

My Raspberry Pi 4 won't boot anymore, there is no picture on the monitor, and both LEDS (red, green) are on all the time, they do not blink. I formatted the SD card with SD Card Formatter and formatted the external USB3 SSD drive, and I flashed the Raspbian image with Etcher. I have tried boot with the bootloader, but still, red and green LEDs are on all the time.

While the Raspberry Pi was working, it was booting and running Raspbian from USB3 SSD.

What to do next to get the Pi working again?

**Update** with info from comment:
It was booting from the sd card, and the raspbian OS was on the ssd.

Comment: [Pi4 Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151&sid=ec118b286843110a1175ec84a250a7dc#p1485558)

Comment: Do not include download links. If necessary link to a web page.

Comment: `it was booting and running raspbian from usb3 ssd` - really? your pi4 can boot from usb? I didn't think that was a thing yet

Comment: your right, it was booting from the sd card, and the raspbian OS was on the ssd.

Comment: have you tried a different sd card?

Comment: I think this is the problem with flashing using Etcher. This software destroyed my 64GB V30 microSDXC (search forums for "Etcher destroys cards") and then the RPi is unable to boot. My destroyed SDXC has never showed up in disks (diskpart etc) since flashing with Etcher. Formatting failed as the card is not visible in system, so neither Rufus helped (device not found).

Comment: I managed to fix it - the problem was probably in using Etcher and "not so fully SDXC compatible" card reader. Etcher somehow flashed the SDXC with success result (it messaged so) but the card reader made an unusable card. The card was then unreadable in all not so old, older and ancient card readers except the newly bought one really SDXC compatible (usb 3 Verbatim). This one showed all 3 partitions, data, everything. So I formatted the card, got rid of partitions and flashed a new OS - BUT USING imager - so I don´t know if Etcher is working properly or not.